# search key, in all fields mentioned in xml

Tags: solr, solarium

I am new to solarium and i am using version 2. I have created the schema, and i need to know on how to pass the search key which should search in all fields OR few fields as per the xml.

Ex : my fields as something like this. `"title", "description", "keywords" etc.` So when user types some word as `"xyz"` it should search in all the above mentioned fields and result me the output. It should search not only has exact but it should be something like our `sql "like"`

The solarium sample examples didn't come up handy.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT _ FIELDS USED

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
```

All my fields type is text_general.. I use solr 4.2.1

Comment: and my solr version is 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your schema.xml to

1. Use [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) to combine title, description, keywords into a single field, and then search on that field.
2. Use [EdgeNGramFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) filter to break the works into fragments so as to match the sql like behaviour.

e.g.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<field name="all_fields" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="all_fields"/> 
...............
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jayendra. I added point number 1 as <copyField source="*" dest="all_fields"/> and regarding point 2, do i have to add the <fieldType> ..... </fieldType> without any change as mentioned in the link EdgeNGramFilterFactory ????

Comment: hey i did so...sorry to bother you more...how can i achieve in client side ? i.e. how will i pass from client side ? i am using solarium for the client side ! Is there any documentation that you can refer me too OR any other alternative

Comment: I just tried with this. http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?defType=dismax&q=surgery nothing is comming up !!!! what is wrong here ???

Comment: hey jayendra it isn't working for me. what would be the error ?? i tried with this it returns only if i pass the field name and that too it doesn't work as "like" http://localhost:8983/solr/select?start=0&rows=100&df=all_fields&q=title:surgery returns only on successful match i.e. exact match

Comment: you should search on the the all_fields e.g. q=all_fields:surgery

Comment: i tried that as well. http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=all_fields:surgery&wt=json returns 0. if i change all_fields to title OR description it works

Comment: HERE IS MY schema.xml  <field name="all_fields" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"
    multiValued="true"/>  .............................................<copyField source="title" dest="all_fields"/>
<copyField source="video_url" dest="all_fields"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="all_fields"/>
 ... other fields as well

Comment: whats the fieldtype configuration for text_general ?? have your reindex your data ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29524/discussion-between-sandy-and-jayendra)

Comment: i have added that in discussion chat...it wasn't allowing me to add a length content

Comment: cant access the chat. you can details to the question itself

Comment: its seems partial. Are you using the same analysis at both query and index time. And the edit does not should the edge gram filter so your partial matches would not work. Can you just try using the field type defined in my answer, reload the core and reindex the data and check again

Comment: Is there a way i can send you my schema ? i added the analyzer EdgeNGramFilterFactory in that and tried too....

Comment: Yes, i use the same analysis. Is there a way i can send you my schema ? i added the analyzer EdgeNGramFilterFactory in that and tried too....Not only partial matches it is not even working for "all_fields" search

Comment: Hey i found some vague behaviour. The keyword is searching in middle of the word..for ex: if a sentence contains a word "sample" and when searched for "amp" it returns that record which is not required. So which is the concern here ???